# Tab bar controller selectedIndex or SelectedViewController accessor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, selectedindex

I have created a tabbar based application which contains, let say, 3 tabs. In my first tab, I have 3 UIButtons. on clicking button 1, a new viewcontroller 1 is loaded and the tab 1 is highlighted as selected. On clicking button 2,  a different view is loaded (Viewcontroller 2) and tab 2 should be highlighted as selected tab (Remember, this viewcontroller 2 is not the root view controller of tab 2) and on clicking button 3, again a new view is shown (viewcontroller 3) and tab 3 should be highlighted as selected (Remember, this viewcontroller 3 is not the root view controller of tab 3).
So, what I want to do is, I want a particular tab to be shown as selected (or highlighted), but dont want to load its root view controller.
I have tried using tabbarcontroller.selectedindex = 1 on clicking of button 1, but it went in vain. Because what happened was tab 1 got selected and the view being shown to me was not viewcontroller 2. Instead it was the root view controller of tab 2. Somebody pls get me out of this mess....

Comment: your question is really confusing and hard to read because you don't space anything out and you don't explain things completely enough and maybe it might be useful if you added some graphics or something to illustrate the problem better have you considered looking at tutorials for tab bars [like this one](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_iPhone_Multiview_Application_using_the_Tab_Bar). do you create your tab bars via a xib or programatically? if the latter please post some code & if former maybe a screenshot. and i hope your day is going really well over there thanks very much.

Comment: As I understand, you want to load three different views and highlight the tabs. Now, why don't you make vc2 and vc3 as rootviewcontrollers ? because if they are not, then why to use tab-bars to show fake highlights ? It will only create confusion in user's mind. just imagine, you press btn 2 and vc2 is loaded with tab2 highlighted. Now, the user taps tab2 again, and suddenly the view changes to tab2 root vc. Now, does it sounds cool ?

Answer (score 0):

If that is indeed your requirement, the best way is to create a 'fake' tab bar using custom uiimageview. You will need three imageview and change the images accordingly as you tap the buttons.